# Automatic adapter generation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, f#

My application has a C# library `Baz.dll` that references a **3rd-party** (other team) library `Foo.dll`, which contains class `FooActuator`, which is directly used by `Baz`. I want to break this dependency by declaring an interface `IActuator`, and have a controller that instantiates the proper implementation of `IActuator` and sends that to `Baz`. And I cannot change `Foo`.

The problem is, there are a bunch of classes in this scenario, and I don't want to write an [adapter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774259/Adapter-Design-Pattern-Csharp) all the time. I'm looking for something like this:

```
FooActuator real = new FooActuator();
IActuator adapter = BuildAdapter<IActuator>(real); // generates adapter for me
Baz.Process(adapter);
```

Is there a library or .NET feature that provides this? I wish for something that I can copy or extend (ie already does some class and assembly generation), rather than using System.Reflection.Emit from scratch.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need the adapter pattern here. Why can't you let `FooActuator` implement `IActuator` and use (for example) an IoC container?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make `FooActuator` act as if it inherited from `IActuator` even though it doesn't in the code?  If so, is there some reason you don't want to have `FooActuator : IActuator`?

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question. A key information was really missing: `Foo` is from another team. I can't touch that. The reason for having `IActuator` is allow `Baz` to be unitarily tested, as usual.

Comment: As a side note - if you have *another team* building stuff that you need to use, but there's no way you can work with common abstractions, you may have an organizational problem.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I think you are assuming too much. There are a bunch of 3rd-party libraries provided by different teams, communities and organizations, that have a clear, well-defined purpose, for which no abstract interface is necessary. The consumers of these libraries may choose to call it directly or to isolate calls through interfaces and adapters.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you may take a look at [Impromptu interface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface) library. After you install it you can do following:

```
FooActuator real = new FooActuator();
IActuator adapter = Impromptu.ActLike<IActuator>(real);
Baz.Process(adapter);
```

What *Impromptu interface* library actually does, it create a new type at runtime using Reflection Emit and the new type implements `IActuator` interface. When some collaborators are calling methods from `IActuator` interface, these calls are delegated to `FooActuator` encapsulated instance (this mean that the method names in `FooActuator` and `IActuator` must match).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're grasping at Inversion of Control and, for reasons unknown, don't want to go all the way there.  The most straightforward approach, to my mind, would be to have `Foo` refernce `Baz`, and your `FooActuator` conform to the interface `IActuator`:

```
public class FooActuator : IActuator
...
```

This would require a refernce from `Foo.dll` to `Baz.dll` (you've inverted control).  You could take it a step further with some dependency injection so that `IActuator`s could be resolved at runtime, using something like `Activator.CreateInstance()` or LINQ to Expressions (which should perform better and give you some more powerful options):

```
Type iActuatorType = Type.GetType(fqnOfClassAndAssembly);
Func<IActuator> tActuatorInstance = null;
if (t != null)
    // tActuatorInstance will be instantiated after this call, if the type can be found
    tActuatorInstance = Expression.Lambda<Func<IActuator>>(Expression.New(iActuatorType)).Compile();
```

This would relieve you of the need to have every implementation of `IActuator` known at compile time, but still maintain that whatever class you try to "adapt" to `IActuator` will definitely contain the methods you expect it to.  In other words, this will force the adapter logic to be written into the implementation of the class itself - and could still allow you to use the Adapter pattern if you **really** had a (closed source/unmodifiable) class that needed it:

```
public class BatActuatorAdapter : BatActuator, IActuator
// methods and properties in here to manipulate BatActuator, which you wouldn't otherwise be able to manipulate.
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't change `Foo` (I have edited my question to let it more clear). The implementation of all adapters must be plain wrappers, that's why I was looking for a code-generation solution.